# android version 12 JNI malloc return null

Tags: android, android-ndk, malloc, android-12

Uncompress the file in the existing cpp file and create a file with a different extension.
For that reason, I call and use the cpp source with `JNI`. On `android 11` it works fine, but on `android 12` the problem occurs.

The problem is that the return of `malloc` in the c++ file called by JNI is `null`. Is there a way to use `malloc` in `android 12`?

This is part of my code.

```
//JAVA
String myFile = //cache memory path;
String copyFile = //cache memory path;

int res = GetFileData(myFile, copyFile);

///C++
const char* szMyFile= env->GetStringUTFChars(myFile, nullptr); //jstring -> const char*
const char* szCopyFile = env->GetStringUTFChars(copyFile, nullptr); //jstring -> const char*

///malloc
ptr_entry_info = (st_entrymodel_info *)malloc(entry_cnt * sizeof(st_entrymodel_info)); //return NULL
```

**Edit**
In the part of allocating `malloc`, `entry_cnt` indicates the number of files. `entry_cnt` is 1.

```
entry_cnt = 1;
ptr_entry_info = (st_entrymodel_info *)malloc(entry_cnt * sizeof(st_entrymodel_info)); //Not NULL
```

The problem is that if I initialize `entry_cnt` back to 1, it doesn't give me an error. But `entry_cnt` is already 1.

Comment: Random guess: you are trying to allocate a gigantic amount of memory and your IS simply refuses to?

Comment: @Botje That doesn't seem to be the case. Because it works normally on `android 11`.

Comment: Well, it doesn't now. I doubt Google "broke" `malloc` on purpose, so you need to investigate what you were doing wrong previously that is now no longer accepted. Also check logcat.

Comment: If allocating too much memory is the problem, is there a solution?

Comment: It's not a matter of memory allocation. I don't have a lot of memory to allocate.

Comment: _" if I initialize entry_cnt back to 1, it doesn't give me an error. But entry_cnt is already 1"_ Apparently not? In any case, it's impossible for us to verify that with only the snippets of code you've shown us.

Comment: So, is `NDK` affected by `android version`??? If affected, how should I build according to `android version`??